# Dynamic web dashboard

Tags: asp.net, charts, dashboard, kpi

I have an existing software that monitors machines. (I have a DB, a web server, and a winforms client). What I would like to do is to build a dynamic dashboard that will show key indicators in charts, gauges etc...

I would like to let the user define what controls to use and how to arrange their layouts.
I found [ducksboard](http://ducksboard.com/) very intersting, but I need something that is more specialized in showing real-time charts (may include large series of points for example).

Is there any solution that combines the dynamic layout ducksboard offers
with the charting abilities of tools like [Dundas Dashboard](http://www.dundas.com/dashboard/)?

Many thanks,
Omer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also there exists an alternative with touch device and responsive layout support.

See online demo at www.jdash.net/demo

More info can be found at www.jdash.net

Short info:

What is JDash.NET

jDash.Net is an Asp.Net Web Forms control library which allows you to easily and seemlessly integrate end user designed dashboards into your application. JDash.Net is browser and database independent.

Easy Development Using ASP.NET

Simply, develop regular Asp.Net user controls – ascx. JDash.Net automatically converts your user controls into drag-drop dashlets which in turn your users use dashlets to design their dashboards.